Cannot connect to running Docker container from locally run Golang
I have a container running on my local with
docker run \
    --publish 8081:8081 \
    --publish 10250-10255:10250-10255 \
    --interactive \
    --tty \
    mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest   

I am able to run in Chrome just fine, https://localhost:8081/etc/etc.
However I must now write a Go program to make an API call to the running container.  I get:
Post "https://172.17.0.2:8081/dbs": dial tcp 172.17.0.2:8081: connect: no route to host


Am I missing something here, do I need to further expose the ports?
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/data/azcosmos"
)

func main() {
    const (
        cosmosDbEndpoint = "https://localhost:8081/"
        cosmosDbKey = "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw=="
        dbname = "db5"
    )
    cred, err := azcosmos.NewKeyCredential(cosmosDbKey)
    handle(err)
    client, err := azcosmos.NewClientWithKey(cosmosDbEndpoint, cred, nil)
    handle(err)
    databaseProperties := azcosmos.DatabaseProperties{ID: dbname}
    _, err = client.CreateDatabase(context.Background(), databaseProperties, nil)
    handle(err)
}

Tried running
set http_proxy=
set https_proxy=

Note that you have to import a cert as in
curl -k https://localhost:8081/_explorer/emulator.pem > ~/emulatorcert.crt
then for example in Mac go to the keychain, add the cert, and trust it

You almost never need to look up the container-internal IP addresses, and they're unreachable in many common environments.  Is your Go program running directly on the host?  If you're using Docker Desktop or if you're using Docker directly on a native-Linux host, you should be able to connect to localhost and one of the published ports (the first number in the --publish options).

Can you specify which host you ask of? I am running the Go program on my local machine, and the Docker Desktop on my local machine, and the API to be connected to (it's a database emulator) is running on Docker Desktop and published to localhost:8081

localhost:8081 is not the same as 172.17.0.2:8081; please show a Minimal, Reproducible Example (we can run your docker run, but don't have access to your Go code).

Running this on my machine I get failed to retrieve account properties: Get "https://localhost:8081/": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (expected as I have not setup the cert). Note: This assumes you are running the Go code locally (not in a container).

you have to create a cert and import it curl -k https://localhost:8081/_explorer/emulator.pem > ~/emulatorcert.crt

Your code would work if you ran it from a docker container on the same network as the emulator (and used the appropriate address). To access this from the host you need to override the emulators IP address with AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE i.e.
docker run -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE=127.0.0.1 --publish 8081:8081 --publish 10250-10255:10250-10255 --interactive --tty mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest

Without this setting the emulator will tell clients to connect to it's docker assigned IP (which is not reachable from the host machine).
Note that you can avoid the need to load the certificate into your local certificate store by using something like the following:
func main() {
    const (
        cosmosDbEndpoint = "https://localhost:8081/"
        cosmosDbKey      = "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw=="
        dbname           = "db5"
    )
    cred, err := azcosmos.NewKeyCredential(cosmosDbKey)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    client, err := azcosmos.NewClientWithKey(cosmosDbEndpoint, cred, &azcosmos.ClientOptions{
        ClientOptions: azcore.ClientOptions{
            Transport: &http.Client{
                Transport: &http.Transport{
                    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    databaseProperties := azcosmos.DatabaseProperties{ID: dbname}
    _, err = client.CreateDatabase(context.Background(), databaseProperties, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

